# Can't make a simple modification of a pdf using Fpdf and Fpdi

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I need your need for a problem which I know was asked a few times in different forum, but that I can't solve, probably because I'm a newbie. If I resolve a problem, another one is coming... until I goes back to my first problem etc...
I'm just trying to import a pdf using Fpdi and add a text.
I tried so many things that I can't remember everything!

This is what I'm doing:

```
<?php
include_once('includes/FPDF/fpdf.php');
include_once('includes/Fpdi/src/autoload.php');

use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

$pdf= new Fpdi();
$pdf-> AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile('includes/TCPDF/doc/report.pdf');
$tplAgence = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->SetXY(20,20);
$pdf->Write(0,"Come on, write something!");
 
$pdf->Output('hourra.pdf','D');
```

The beginning of my Fpdi.php looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace setasign\src;

use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReferenceException;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\PdfParserException;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\Type\PdfIndirectObject;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\Type\PdfNull;

class Fpdi extends FpdfTpl
{
    use FpdiTrait;
...
```

I don't know if I have the wrong libraries (if there are any) but the different files for the 2 libraries are:

[image]

What I have at the moment is this:

*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "setasign\src\FpdfTpl" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\testProject\includes\Fpdi\src\Fpdi.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testProject\includes\Fpdi\src\autoload.php(18): require_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\testProject\testPDF.php(25): {closure}('setasign\Fpdi\F...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testProject\includes\Fpdi\src\Fpdi.php on line 22*

Please, let me know if you need anything else. Actually, I just need an example I could use as a beginning for my project.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why didn't you install these files properly through Composer if you already have a `composer.json`?

Comment: @NicoHaase the `composer.json` in the screenshot is from FPDI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you modified files of FPDI. This:

```
<?php
namespace setasign\src;
```

...is wrong.
Why did you removed the copyright and license header and modified the namespace?

Do a fresh install and you're ready to go. You can find the original header for comparsion e.g. [here](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI/blob/master/src/Fpdi.php#L11).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Like I said, I did so many things that I get lost. I followed your advices and everything works nicely. Back to work...